# When connecting to a JMS server, does the client have to be using the same API that the server is using?

Tags: api, jms, tibco, openjms

For example, since our server is using TIBCO EMS, would I be able to connect to it using OpenJMS or WeblogicJMS?

Answer (score 1):

JMS standardizes the API, but not the wire-protocol.  So all JMS implementations are based on the same API *interfaces*, but you will require different *implementation* libraries/jar-files in your class-path that match the server you're connecting to.  In the TIBCO EMS case, if you're connecting to a EMS, you'll need `tibjms.jar` and possibly other of this jars; you cannot use something from OpenJMS etc. instead since they use different wire-protocols.

JMS is pretty much the same as JDBC in this regard.